# JProfiler is slow Retransforming 17586 class files

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, jprofiler

Earlier when starting trial it was loading immediately.
Now (on the same application) I see:

```
JProfiler> Retransforming 17586 class files.
```

in logs in IntelliJ and it really takes a while (over 10 minutes and still waiting).

I'm running the app on my local machine.

I'm attaching by clicking in IntelliJ `Attach to JVM` and then selecting process in the window below:

[image]

After that i get:

[image]

and clicked `ok`.

Comment: How's your connectivity to the machine running the application?

Comment: it's on localhost

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the dialog that is shown after you select the attached JVM? Do you connect with a saved session or with the "Quick attach" feature?

Comment: Sure. edited the question.

Comment: I mean the dialog after that one

Comment: ok - I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like JProfiler is very slow in retransforming, which is bad.

I ended up limiting classes by selecting package filters and they really helped.

https://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/help.pdf

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: sure, a solution is to limit the number of classes by using package filters like mentioned